# How to manually calculate correlation coefficiant using numpy for loops in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, correlation, pearson-correlation

So I am taking my first proper course in Python and I have stumbled upon some issues trying to calculate the correlation coefficient for a data set. I know that I can just use np.coercoef but I would like to be able to do it "by hand" also. I have tried various combinations of the following code but I keep getting an answer that is somehow higher than the answer that np.coercoef gives me (approximately 0.62 compared to 0.57).

I was hoping that someone on here could maybe help me identify the problem in my code?

Best regards,

```
k_m = np.array([22, 48, 76, 10, 22, 4, 68, 44, 10, 76, 14, 56])
km = np.array([63, 39, 61, 30, 51, 44, 74, 78, 55, 58, 41, 69])

gns_k_m = 0
gns_km = 0
cov = 0
sum_k_m = 0
sum_km = 0

for k in range(len(k_m)):
    gns_k_m += k_m[k]/len(k_m)

for k in range(len(km)):
    gns_km += km[k]/len(km)
    
print(gns_k_m, gns_km)

for k in range(len(k_m)):
    cov += (k_m[k]-gns_k_m)*(km[k]-gns_km)/(len(k_m)-1)

print(cov)

for k in range(len(k_m)):
    sum_k_m += (k_m[k]-gns_k_m)**2

sa_k_m = np.sqrt(sum_k_m/len(k_m))

for k in range(len(km)):
    sum_km += (km[k]-gns_km)**2
    
sa_km = np.sqrt(sum_km/len(km))

cor = cov/(sa_k_m*sa_km)

print(cor)
print(np.corrcoef(k_m,km))
```

Comment: I think the issue is a statistical one, not a computational one.  Looking briefly, why is there the '-1' in the calculation of variance?

Comment: you sure you are comparing same stuff ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `np.corrcoef` uses a normalisation where the covariance is divided by `len(k_m)`, not by your `len(k_m) - 1`.

Hence, if you re-normalize the result given by `np.corrcoef`, you obtain the same value as given by your manual implementation.

```
In [26]: new_res = (np.corrcoef(k_m, km) * len(k_m) / (len(k_m) - 1))[0, 1]

In [28]: np.allclose(new_res, cor)
Out[28]: True

In [29]: new_res
Out[29]: 0.6165427925911239
```

Comment: Okay thanks! What does it mean when you put [0,1] at the end of the first line?

Comment: ```np.corrcoef``` returns a 2x2 matrix with the Pearson correlation coefficients, and ```[0, 1]``` is an index which corresponds to the "upper right" entry of this matrix. This is the correlation coefficient of ```k_m``` and ```km```.